# Fancybox not working on school's server but works on localhost

Tags: jquery

https://studentpages.scad.edu/~jiashu20/

I'm new to dreamweaver and this is my first time making a website. But when I tried using fancybox, it works perfectly on localhost but when I try to upload to school's server, all it does is when clicking images it pop up a new window instead of having fancybox effect.

What should I do?

Comment: Check the browser's console for errors.

Comment: sorry I'm completely new.. how can I check it?

Comment: Typically you can press F12, switch to the console tab, and reload the page.

Comment: I assume you're asking about the artwork page? Notice the weird bit of JavaScript fragment appearing as text at the top of the page. That's because in line 22 of your HTML, you have a closing script tag that isn't supposed to be there, so the intended script isn't running as JavaScript. In all likelihood, the errors caused by that code not running are bringing all JavaScript processing to a halt, and that's why FancyBox isn't working--it never gets a chance to run.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is this message:

```
Blocked loading mixed active content "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
```

So your site does not allow you to load a script using http while your site is loaded in https. Download and place jQuery and your other script and css files locally to fix this. Or simply switch the url of those files to https if they support it.

Read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent

Comment: I'm a little bit confused... how exactly should I do this?

Comment: Look for http ://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js in your project and add an s after http.